# Why my method won't run in a class without error msg

Tags: python

I am running an example from the book "Hello World! Third Edition: Computer Programming for Kids and Other Beginners", and ran into the following problem.

```
class HotDog: 
    def __init__ (self): 
        self.cooked_level = 0 
        self.cooked_string = "Raw" 
        self.condiments = [] 

    def cook(self, time):          
        if self.cooked_level > 8:
            self.cooked_string = "Charcoal" 
        elif self.cooked_level > 5:
            self.cooked_string = "Well-done"
        elif self.cooked_level > 3:
            self.cooked_string = "Medium"
        else:
            self.cooked_string = "Raw"

myDog = HotDog() 
print(myDog.cooked_level) 
print(myDog.cooked_string) 
print(myDog.condiments) 

print("Now I'm going to cook the hot dog") 
myDog.cook(4)
print(myDog.cooked_level) 
print(myDog.cooked_string)
```

When I ran the script, here is what I got:

```
0
Raw
[]
Now I'm going to cook the hot dog
0
Raw
```

so the `myDog.cook(4)` did not run and I did not get an error msg.
I wonder which part of this script went wrong...

Thanks!

Comment: You're passing in time but not using it in method `cook`.

Comment: **time** is not factored at any point in **cook()**. maybe try updating **cooked_level** using **time** before checking it

Comment: Your cook method runs correctly but it just does nothing. Have a look at it again ;)
Maybee add self.cooked_level += time at the beginning of the method

Answer (score 1):

You only need to update your `self.cooked_level` in your `cook()` method.

```
class HotDog: 
    ...
    ...

    def cook(self, time):
        self.cooked_level += time    #<--- only add this line      
        if self.cooked_level > 8:
            self.cooked_string = "Charcoal" 
        ...
        ...
```